# Stuck on large numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i've got a problem. I need to prove that $43^{47}-17^{17}$ is divisible by $10$.

I think that somehow I have to prove that the number ends with a $0$.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does the title have to do with the question???

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: When you say 43 times 47, you mean $43^{47}$ or $43\times 47$?

Comment: Assuming you meant $43*47-17*17$, this is easy enough to do by hand (and I assume you meant + instead of -).

Comment: sorry im not a native speaker. I meant in as  43*43*43*43....(total times of 47) - 17*17*17*17 (total times of 17). and i meant - 

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: Since the expression is clearly even you can work on divisibility by $5$ rather than $10$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

- $43^{47}\equiv3^{47}\equiv3^{4\cdot11+3}\equiv(3^4)^{11}\cdot3^3\equiv81^{11}\cdot27\equiv1^{11}\cdot7\equiv1\cdot7\equiv7\pmod{10}$
- $17^{17}\equiv7^{17}\equiv7^{4\cdot4+1}\equiv(7^4)^{4}\cdot7^1\equiv2401^{4}\cdot7\equiv1^{4}\cdot7\equiv1\cdot7\equiv7\pmod{10}$

Comment: Looks more like a complete solution to me :-)

Comment: @A.G.: Yeah well let's just call it a "BIG HINT" :)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $43\equiv3\pmod{10},17\equiv7,\phi(10)=4$

$$43^{47}-17^{17}\equiv3^3-7^1\pmod{10}$$

Comment: When you see the question with "43 times 47", you immediately think that the author means $43^{47}$? Because I immediately think the author means $43\times 47$.

Comment: @user37238, I believe it to be exponent as $43\cdot47-17\cdot17\equiv2\not\equiv0\pmod{10}$

Comment: i meant it as (43*43*43*43*43*43....) total times of 47

Comment: @Arnas, That is same as $43^{47}$

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee yes